# Split multi-zone air conditioner (not a heat pump)

Tags: air-conditioning, mini-split

I'm considering adding air conditioning to my home in Seattle. I have a modern, high efficiency gas furnace for heat. It would be easiest for me to add air conditioning using mini split technology. I would like to buy a two-zone air conditioning unit (one compressor located outside with two air handlers located inside). I would prefer to obtain cooling with a split system without having to use a heat pump. I prefer the simplicity and reliability of a pure A/C system. If others have implemented such a system I'd appreciate suggestions for equipment brands that are reliable. Finally, I'm not interested in being sold on the benefits of heat pumps. I understand heat pump technology, like it for certain applications and don't want it as the solution to my cooling problem. Thanks.

Comment: So you want a mini-split, but you want them to delete the internal reversing valve that lets it both cool and heat.   As far as your conceptions about simplicity and reliability, you might find [a technology briefer on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J52mDjZzto) helpful.

Comment: I hate to break it to you but a "pure A/C system" is a heat pump.  The difference between what we traditionally call an "A/C system" and what we call a "heat pump" is that the heat pump has a reversing system that lets it pump heat in either direction.

Comment: Do you realize that a mini split IS a heat pump. The only difference is the inside heads have there own fans and controls instead of putting the coil in the existing duct and using the existing fan & ducting. Edit: I should have read the other comments stating the same thing. The PNW is a good climate for minis , however I would consider a simple outside ac unit and coil all it lacks from being a “heat pump” is a reversing valve and a fancy thermostat that can control both.

Comment: I fully understand the differences between AC compressors and heat pumps. I want to avoid the complexity and reduction in reliability associated with reversing valves and other parts of heat pumps that I don’t need.

Comment: Mitsubishi, Daikin, and several other manufacturers make cooling-only mini split systems. Find a local dealer in your area and they should be able to help you.

Comment: You mention a highly efficient gas furnace. Do you realize that a good heat pump is 3 times more efficient moving heat? You can also heat the local area instead of heating the whole house. Then there is the added benefit if the furnace is down for service and you have an alternate heat source.